# How to get all corresponding StyleSheets of a HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, css, cssom

I am wondering how get the corresponding StyleSheet-Objects of a HTMLElement via JavaScript. Since this logic is somehow implemented in every browser's Inspector-Tools, it should be possible from within the page too - I hope.

[image: ChromeDevTools Element Inspector]

There must be something like

```
var cssStyleDeklaration = window.getComputedStyle($0);
var cssRule = cssStyleDeklaration.color;
console.log(cssRule.parentStyleSheet.href);

->> http://the.style.sheet/source.css
```

I read all docs about CSSOM-API but found no way.

Comment: There is no such interface available in window context

Comment: You can get the linkElement then linkElement.href would contain the location, or get the styleElement then styleElement.src, or you would have to parse the text in the styleElement if using @import 'yourURL.css';.

Comment: This is done the other way around: iterate through all the stylesheets and check if your Element `matches` the cssRules's `selectorText`.